# What is the benefit of "from __future__ import annotations" if classes are imported for type hints anyway?

Tags: python, python-3.7, type-hinting, python-typing

What is the benefit of importing `from __future__ import annotations`? When I understand it right I should stop unnecessary typing import in runtime.

In my example `HelloWorld` is only needed for typing. But with this code the output always is:

`Should this happen?
x = World!`

When I remove `from hello import HelloWorld` the typing help in PyCharm does not longer work (I can understand this, because it does not understand where `HelloWorld` is from).

```
from __future__ import annotations

from hello import HelloWorld

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def hello(x: str, hello: HelloWorld = None):
        if hello is not None:
            print('hello.data_01 =', hello.data_01)
        print('x =', x)


    hello('World!')
```

hello.py

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class HelloWorld:
    data_01: str
    data_02: str


print("Should this happen?")
```

So my question is if I still need to do `from hello import HelloWorld` what benefits do I get from `from __future__ import annotations`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `from __future__ import annotations` import has one core advantage: it makes using [forward references](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#class-name-forward-references) cleaner.

For example, consider this (currently broken) program.

```
# Error! MyClass has not been defined yet in the global scope
def foo(x: MyClass) -> None:
    pass

class MyClass:
    # Error! MyClass is not defined yet, in the class scope
    def return_copy(self) -> MyClass:
        pass
```

This program will actually *crash* when you try running it at runtime: you've tried using 'MyClass' before it's actually ever defined. In order to fix this before, you had to either use the type-comment syntax or wrap each 'MyClass' in a string to create a *forward reference*:

```
def foo(x: "MyClass") -> None:
    pass

class MyClass:
    def return_copy(self) -> "MyClass":
        pass
```

Although this works, it feels very janky. Types should be types: we shouldn't need to have to manually convert certain types into strings just to make types play nicely with the Python runtime.

We can fix this by including the `from __future__ import annotations` import: that line automatically makes *all* types a string at runtime. This lets us write code that looks like the first example without it crashing: since each type hint is actually a string at runtime, we're no longer referencing something that doesn't exist yet.

And typecheckers like mypy or Pycharm won't care: to them, the type looks the same no matter how Python itself chooses to represent it.

---

One thing to note is that this import does not, by itself, let us avoid importing things. It simply makes it cleaner when doing so.

For example, consider the following:

```
from expensive_to_import_module import MyType

def blah(x: MyType) -> None: ...
```

If `expensive_to_import_module` does a lot of startup logic, that might mean it takes a non-negligible amount of time to import `MyType`. This won't really make a difference once the program is actually running, but it *does* make the time-to-start slower. This can feel particularly bad if you're trying to write short-lived command-line style programs: the act of adding type hints can sometimes make your program feel more sluggish when starting up.

We *could* fix this by making `MyType` a string while hiding the import behind an `if TYPE_CHECKING` guard, like so:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

# TYPE_CHECKING is False at runtime, but treated as True by type checkers.
# So the Python interpreters won't do the expensive import, but the type checker
# will still understand where MyType came from!
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from expensive_to_import_module import MyType

# This is a string reference, so we don't attempt to actually use MyType
# at runtime.
def blah(x: "MyType") -> None: ...
```

This works, but again looks clunky. Why should we need to add quotes around the last type? The `annotations` future import makes the syntax for doing this a little smoother:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from expensive_to_import_module import MyType

# Hooray, no more quotes!
def blah(x: MyType) -> None: ...
```

Depending on your point-of-view, this may not seem like a huge win. But it *does* help make using type hints much more ergonomic, makes them feel more "integrated" into Python, and (once these become enabled by default) removes a common stumbling block newcomers to PEP 484 tend to trip over.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. One question, do we know when this behavior will become the default and when `from __future__ import annotations` will not be needed anymore? It seems like it was suppose to be 3.10, yet I am running on that version and I needed the import to get rid of the quotes.